# Регулярное выражение для возврата слов по условию в виде списков

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть текст вида

> продолжаем делиться техническими характеристиками публикаций в
> facebook сегодня подготовили для вас гайд по рекламным форматам
> смотрите в карточках #tag_1 #tag_2

код

```
import re
text = 'продолжаем делиться техническими характеристиками публикаций в facebook сегодня подготовили для вас гайд по рекламным форматам смотрите в карточках #tag_1 #tag_2, а еще #tag_14'
tag2 = re.findall('#tag_.?', text)
print(tag2)
```

возвращает список из трёх элементов:

> ['#tag_1', '#tag_2', '#tag_1']

Нужно, чтобы код возвращал не список элементов, а несколько списков в зависимости от числа найденных по условию элементов, то есть

> ['#tag_1'], ['#tag_2'], ['#tag_14']

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не соответствует самому вопросу. Вы их скоррелируйте как-то....

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тогда вот так

```
import re
s = []
text = 'продолжаем делиться техническими характеристиками публикаций в facebook сегодня подготовили для вас гайд по рекламным форматам смотрите в карточках #tag_1 #tag_2, а еще #tag_14'
s.extend([i] for i in re.findall('#tag_\d+', text))
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
text = 'продолжаем делиться техническими характеристиками публикаций в facebook сегодня подготовили для вас гайд по рекламным форматам смотрите в карточках #tag_1 #tag_2, а еще #tag_14'
tag2 = re.findall('#tag_\d+', text)
print(tag2)
```

Comment: Скажите, зачем изменять свой ответ, полностью переделав его в мой?

Comment: Пардон, в вопросе действительно была ошибка. Исправил ожидаемый результат.